# Experiencing long wait times for job to be created when using Data Connector API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

The company I work for has multiple BIM360 accounts. We use an ETL pipeline to automate the extraction of data from these accounts. The goal is to load this data into our datawarehouse.

In order to do this, we loop through all our accounts. For each account, we post a data request.
After this step, we check if the job has been created. If not, we wait 5 minutes and then check again. Once created, we check if the export is ready and then ingest the data.

Lately we have been noticing extremely long wait times for these jobs to be created. In many cases, it took over one hour per account after which our API token was no longer valid which caused our ETL pipeline to fail.

Is there anything that can be done about this? I would also like to know if there is anything we can do ourselves to improve the performance.

Example job ID's (for Autodesk):
cca436eb-cddc-49db-9efd-3b67c96c514c,
68dd4a6f-290a-4a02-bce8-32a8d8764799,
3f0ec71a-716c-4344-bd5e-b94c82782023

More IDs can be provided if needed.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: firstly, Data Connector API supports callback. When posting a request, you can specify it. It will notify when the job completes or fails. As to the jobs issue, are they finally completed or never ended? I will need to check with engineer about details information

Comment: Hi jro, any chance to check if the jobs finally completed or never ended?